# cgo cross-compile failing to find libraries

Tags: linux, go, cgo

I've written a wrapper around the semaphore functions in linux. This worked for me in the past on Go 1.3 and Go 1.4, but I needed to rebuild my application using this wrapper and it no longer builds with Go 1.6.2 or Go 1.7rc5.

I wrote a simple test application that produces the same errors:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "linux/semaphore"
)

func main() {
    var sema semaphore.Semaphore
    if err := sema.Open("/test", 0644, 1); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    if err := sema.TryWait(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    if err := sema.Post(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Now the program does compile natively (linux/amd64), my issue is when I try to cross-compile for linux/arm (Ti am3352).

Previously all I had to do was:

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=/am335x_toolchain/bin/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi-gcc go build
```

Which now gives the following error:

```
# runtime/cgo
/tmp/go-build820923984/runtime/cgo/_obj/_cgo_export.c:2:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdlib.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

So I specified the include path:

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=/am335x_toolchain/bin/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi-gcc CGO_CFLAGS="-I/am335x_toolchain/include" go build
# runtime/cgo
/am335x_toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi/4.8.3/../../../../armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
/am335x_toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi/4.8.3/../../../../armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/am335x_toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi/4.8.3/../../../../armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Eventually I got to this, which still doesn't work:

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=/am335x_toolchain/bin/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi-gcc CGO_LDFLAGS="-L/am335x_toolchain/lib -pthread" CGO_CFLAGS="-I/am335x_toolchain/include" go build
# runtime/cgo
/am335x_toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi/4.8.3/../../../../armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
/am335x_toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi/4.8.3/../../../../armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/am335x_toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi/4.8.3/../../../../armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/libpthread.so.0
/am335x_toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi/4.8.3/../../../../armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The pthread library does exist:

```
$ ls /am335x_toolchain/lib | grep "libpthread*"
libpthread-2.18.so
libpthread.a
libpthread_nonshared.a
libpthread.so
libpthread.so.0
```

Any pointers on what I need to do to cross-compile with CGO? Seems like with each release I've had more trouble cross-compiling with CGO.

**EDIT:**

I've discovered this is an issue with the host architecture. I get the above issues when running on an x86_64 machine (linux). When I compile with Go 1.6 on a 32bit x86 machine (linux), it builds without errors. Still haven't found a solution of compiling on the 64bit machine.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `$CC` to `$CC_FOR_TARGET`? See [here](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/).

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji- $CC_FOR_TARGET is to be used when building the toolchain using make.bash. $CC is used for cross-compiling a program. I tried rebuilding the toolchain with CC_FOR_TARGET set, but I get the same error when running the go tool.

Comment: Maybe something like `--sysroot /am335x_toolchain/` both in `CGO_CFLAGS` and `CGO_LDFLAGS` would help?

Comment: @RomanKhimov I added `--sysroot /am335x_toolchain/` to both `CGO_CFLAGS` and `CGO_LDFLAGS` and it worked. Thank you for your help. If you writeup an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the problem is that for the cross-compiler to properly find its headers and libraries it needs a [`--sysroot` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html), in your case `--sysroot /am335x_toolchain/` added both to CGO_CFLAGS and CGO_LDFLAGS.